# How to extend the Gradle Kotlin DSL with custom extension functions?

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to build my own extension function, which uses an extension method from `C:/Users/<username>/.gradle/caches/7.3-20211011231002+0000/kotlin-dsl/accessors/5030f2917b46f065859e6c634449b97d/sources/org/gradle/kotlin/dsl/Accessors2oadk7let745pm8ahqypkqzlk.kt:63` - which seems to be something deeply internal.

In my `buildSrc` subproject I want to try to add the following extension function

```
val org.gradle.api.Project.testSources
    get() = sourceSets.getByName("test").output
```

Is there a way to resolve the extension functions defined in the Kotlin DSL (my overall goal is instead of writing `project(":<name>").sourceSets["test"].output`  to write `project(":<name>").testSources`).

I do not really understand why all the extension methods are not available....

The build-gradle.kts of my buildSrc.

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}
```

[Repo](https://github.com/reisi007/reisishot.pictures/blob/327fa437aa91eba2ed1452844c9d3196242d2830/backend-config/build.gradle.kts#L1) (this will not build as one file is missing, which I want to keep private, but that shouldn't matter for this issue)

Answer (score 7):

You can share extension functions, or field extension, within a single project by simply defining them in `.kt` files in `./buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/`. You can then import them into any of the project's `build.gradle.kts` files.

For example, if you create `./buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/my/project/MyExtensions.kt`

- Note that it's a `.kt`, not `.kts` file.
- Also note that the package is set - often IntelliJ forgets to generate it when working in buildSrc!

```kotlin
//MyExtensions.kt
package my.project

val org.gradle.api.Project.testSources
    get() = sourceSets.getByName("test").output // compilation error...
```

But... that code won't work. Because it's in a `.kt` file, not a `.kts`, the Gradle magic won't load the Kotlin DSL `sourceSets` accessor.

For tips on how to access Gradle objects without the Kotlin DSL accessors, looking at the Gradle Plugin development guide is best https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html.

You can also `cmd/ctrl + left click` in the `build.gradle.kts` files to see what the Kotlin DSL accessor is...

```kotlin
// auto-generated Kotlin DSL accessor
/**
 * Retrieves the [sourceSets][org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetContainer] extension.
 */
val org.gradle.api.Project.`sourceSets`: org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetContainer get() =
    (this as org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware).extensions.getByName("sourceSets") as org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetContainer
```

The auto generated code is a good start.

There's a few ways of accessing Gradle objects. Personally I'd prefer to retrieve the [SourceSetContainer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:sourceSets(groovy.lang.Closure)) by type, not by string. And so here's how to fix your field extension.

```kotlin
package my.project

import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetContainer
import org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.findByType

val Project.testSources: SourceSetOutput?
    get() = extensions
        .findByType<SourceSetContainer>()
        ?.getByName("test")
        ?.output
```

Now in `<root>/build.gradle.kts` you can import the extension, and use it as expected.

```kotlin
//build.gradle.kts
import my.project.testSources

project.testSources?.files?.forEach { file: File? ->
    logger.lifecycle("my extension function found a testSources file $file")
}
```

#### Sharing functions with plugins - Extension Aware

You can also share functions with regular Gradle plugins. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware.html. However I don't think defining extension functions is possible.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, highly appreciated :D

Comment: how to do it without usage of buildSrc ?